# Closing BottomSheet of Scaffold if it is open

Tags: flutter

In one widget, I add a `BottomSheet` to a `Scaffold` using the [`showBottomSheet<T>` method](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/showBottomSheet.html).

In another widget, I want to close the BottomSheet if it is open (the BottomSheet may or may not be open when the widget is rendered).

I know you can use `Navigator.pop(context);` but in my case, the BottomSheet is only rendered in certain scenarios so `Navigator.pop(context);` would sometimes remove the required screen.

Is there a way to close the bottom sheet using a method that is the inverse of to `showBottomSheet<T>` (i.e. something in Flutter like a `closeBottomSheet<T>`)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it by using `Key` for your `Scaffold`. Your `showBottomSheet` method returns a [PersistentBottomSheetController](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/PersistentBottomSheetController-class.html) object and this object has a `close` method and you can use it to trigger the closing.

I have created a sample above with Key and Global variables to give you an example. It opens up the bottom sheet within one Widget and closes it from the other one.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Bottom sheet'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
PersistentBottomSheetController controller;

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 200,
            child: Scaffold(
              key: _scaffoldKey,
              body: Container(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _settingModalBottomSheet(context);
                  },
                  child: Text("Show Bottom"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 200,
            child: Scaffold(
              body: Container(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _closeModalBottomSheet();
                },
                child: Text("Hide Bottom"),
              )),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void _settingModalBottomSheet(context) {
  controller =
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showBottomSheet<Null>((BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        child: new Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: new Text(
              'Some title!',
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            )),
        new Text(
          'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ullamcorper massa metus, sed pharetra mauris porttitor et. Nullam ac ultrices leo. Praesent sed consequat risus. ',
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        ),
      ],
    ));
  });
}

void _closeModalBottomSheet() {
  if (controller != null) {
    controller.close();
    controller = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Any Specific reason of nesting a scaffold?

Comment: It may have to do with an error I encountered in my own code where if the `context` passed in to `showBottomSheet()` doesn't have a `Scaffold` ancestor, it errors. The error message is quite helpful in providing options to resolve it. I don't recommend extra `Scaffold`s.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the purpose behind the extra `Scaffold`s in this example. Regardless, example 2 [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/of.html) shows how to get a new, lower context.

Comment: Scaffold is there for simply as an eye candy to actually have a proper scaffolding and background color :) So it is not vital for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

showBottomSheet() is itself a PersistentBottomSheetController, so without having to create controller or key you can also use:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Comment: The OP rules out the use of `Navigator.pop(context)` in case there is no bottom sheet open